# ROS rosmake error

Tags: c++, ros

I am currently working on a project with ROS. I am completely new to ROS and it's features. Currently i'm doing a tutorial on ROS and started using code for the first time. although i do have some experience with c++, i can't figure out what is going wrong. In ROS i use the *rosmake* command and it fails to compile the cpp file/code. Can anyone help me figure out why the error occurs? (and possibly how to fix it?)

below is the cpp file code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "example1_a");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_
msgs::String>("message", 1000);
ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
while (ros::ok())
{
std_msgs::String msg;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << " I am the example1_a node ";
msg.data = ss.str();
//ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
ros::spinOnce();
loop_rate.sleep();
}
return 0;
}
```

And here the build log:

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package chapter2_tutorials
[rosbuild] using multiarch 'x86_64-linux-gnu' for finding Boost
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Skip enable_testing() for dry packages
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/indigo/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build
cd build && make -j8 -l8
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
Scanning dependencies of target example1_a
Scanning dependencies of target example1_b
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
[100%] [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example1_b.dir/src/example1_b.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example1_a.dir/src/example1_a.cpp.o
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:8:42: error: ‘std_’ was not declared in this scope
 ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_
                                          ^
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:8:32: error: parse error in template argument list
 ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_
                                ^
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:9:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const char [8], int)’
 msgs::String>("message", 1000);
                              ^
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:9:30: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note: template<class M> ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool)
     Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, bool latch = false)
               ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:9:30: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 msgs::String>("message", 1000);
                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:302:13: note: template<class M> ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const VoidConstPtr&, bool)
   Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
             ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:302:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:9:30: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 msgs::String>("message", 1000);
                              ^
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1_a.dir/src/example1_a.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1_a.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable ../bin/example1_b
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
[100%] Built target example1_b
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rospc/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This next code is from the second file, which does compile and creates no errors:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "example1_b");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("message", 1000, chatterCallback);
ros::spin();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a strange line-break in the code, that should not be there. C++ can be very sensitive to such errors, and can produce a lot of follow-up errors that are not actual errors, but problems because an earlier errors. Fix the first error and most (maybe even all) of the remaining errors should disappear. Also note that the error messages tells you the exact position (file-name, line-number and even an "arrow" where in the line the error was encountered), use that to locate the error in the source.

Comment: Also, unrelated to the problem and not needed for the compiler, but indentation makes code much more readable by humans. Please indent your code in some way, especially if others will see it (and with "others" you should include yourself in a month, year or more time).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. Can't see why i didn't figure that out.

Comment: Just a side note: Is there a specific reason that you use `rosmake` instead of `catkin`? rosmake is obsolete and should generally not be used for new packages.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. Began using catkin today, works great.

Answer (score 4):

Line breaks in C++ code can only be done in 3 ways :

```
cout<<"Error:This is a really long error "
"message that exceeds the maximum permitted length.\n";
```

or

```
cout<<"Error:This is a really long error \
message that exceeds the maximum permitted length.\n";
```

or

```
c\
o\
u\
t<<"Error:This is a really long error \
message that exceeds the maximum permitted length.\n";
```

other than that, it will throw you errors ...

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_
msgs::String>("message", 1000);
```

By:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("message", 1000);
```

PS : **You should not use *rosmake***. It's an old tool to build your workspace.

**Use** `catkin_make` or `catkin build`.

**Note:** You can't use both *catkin_make* and *catkin build* on the same workspace. If you want to switch you need to clean your workspace. For that it's easy, you have to erase your build, devel and install directory in your workspace folder.

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ sudo rm -r devel build install
```

Alternative ways :

If you use *catkin_make* and want to clean your workspace to switch to *catkin build* use

```
$ catkin_make clean
$ catkin build
```

If you use *catkin build* and want to clean your workspace to switch to *catkin_make* use

```
$ catkin clean
$ catkin_make
```

**rosmake vs catkin:**

Since ROS Groovy, it's not recommended to use rosmake, here is why we use catkin:

- Make better use of all tools provided by Cmake,
- Cmake's C means Cross Platform. The idea is to make ROS more portable on different architectures (ARM) and OS (OS X and Windows).
- With rosbuild each package had its own Cmake, package dependency management was less stable.
- Cmake can compile smarter by parallelizing dependencies.
- Reduce memory space by optimizing dependencies.
- A single installation target which allows companies to run closed and proprietary software on ROS.

**catkin_make vs catkin build**:

Quite the same, but the most recent *catkin build*. Nowadays, some people recommend to switch from *catkin_make* to *catkin build*. The main difference between both is that catkin build has a better isolation package. It will build each package a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++11 for make your project. 
For this use the cmake flag in your command:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11
```

Or

```
catkin build -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11
```